# What if I want to ask a question, but I think that there is another question similar to mine?

Tags: discussion, questions

I wanted to ask a question about if you could turn a function into someone like this: `string.myFunction()`. Now I think that there are other questions out there just like this, its just I don't know what the questions would be called.

So, should I (a) try to find a question like this, or (b) ask the question and probably get it taken down?

Comment: Duplicate questions aren't taken down/deleted under normal circumstances, they just serve as a signpost to the question that has the answer(s).

Comment: Yes, you should try to first find duplicates. You should always research the heck out of your problem before asking a question. If you find a way to make your question truly unique, you could always provide links to near-duplicates and explain how they may be similar but don't fully answer your own specific question.

Comment: If you're having trouble finding an existing question, SO's search isn't great. You'll probably have better luck if you google "site:stackoverflow.com" with some set of possible keywords

Comment: As others suggested - try searching first. If you fail finding something, feel free to ask - maybe there is a duplicate but it's not obvious. Please don't just ask and expect somebody to the actual search for you. Asking a duplicate question where the answer could be found within seconds is *immensely* annoying to deal with and a lot of times will earn you downvotes. By contrast a good duplicate that shows a completely different path to the same solution might be upvoted for being useful.

Comment: "Should I perform research, or should I be lazy?" If I rephrase the question like that, it kind of self-answers itself doesn't it? Research is always the right answer, especially because you'll probably learn two things instead of only the one.

Answer (score 6):

It should probably go without saying that you should **always go with option A *(try to find a question)* first**.

If you are using the Stack Overflow search engine, finding the right posts can be tricky, so I would suggest **searching on Google** *(and checking out the Stack Overflow links if any show up in the search results)*, making sure to **keep switching up your search query** if you fail to find a solution in the search results.

The next thing you can do, seeing that you have the privilege to [talk in chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat), is to **ask in the chatroom corresponding to the programming language** of your problem. For example, [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/17/javascript) is one for JavaScript *(be sure to read their rules)*. Given that you said *"I think that there are other questions out there just like this"*, I would assume that the problem isn't too complicated, so receiving an answer from chat would be really likely.

Finally, if you do end up asking the question on the site, be sure to **link the posts you found** during your search that seems similar to your problem *(I'm sure you'll find plenty given the keywords you would use to search)*, **and explain how they don't solve your problem** to avoid your post getting *(mistakenly)* closed as a duplicate of the other posts.